# How do I add 3rd party CkEditor plugins to the editor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have found a third-party CKEditor plugin I want to add to the editor provided by Drupal core in Drupal 8. What do I need to do to be able to make it possible to add this new option to the editor?

The plugin I would like to add is the image2 plugin (called enhanced images) found on the CKEDITOR site. Based on my research, it appears I'd need to add a YAML and a module file to what CKEDITOR provides.

Comment: @Frank Are you asking about a plugin you want to implement (or you implemented), or are you asking how to add a plugin provided by others? In the latter case, may you at least tell us which plugin do you want to use?

Comment: I'd like to start with the image2 plugin (called enhanced images) on the CKEDITOR site.  Based on other research, it appears I'd need to add a yml file and a module file to what CKEDITOR provides.